# Process of graphing a function $\arccos(\ln{(\frac{x+1}{x-3})})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, graphing-functions

$$\arccos\left(\log{\left(\frac{x+1}{x-3}\right)}\right)$$

We  need to graph this function. I can graph $g(x)=\log{\left(\frac{x+1}{x-3}\right)}$ but I get trouble when I want to graph  $\arccos(g(x))$.

What is the easiest thought process for graphing such functions.

Comment: In what interval?¨

Comment: What I would do first is to check 1) Starting value. Normally at the origin but now it's shifted to the right/left. 2) Limit. 3) If the function is monotonic or oscillating.

Comment: @vitamind just so that it is obvious from the graph where the function is located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\arccos\left(\ln{\frac{x+1}{x-3}}\right)$$
domain of $\arccos$ is $[-1,1]$ thus we must have
$$-1\le \ln{\frac{x+1}{x-3}}\le 1;\;\frac{x+1}{x-3}> 0$$

$$ x\leq -\frac{3+e}{e-1}\lor x\geq \frac{3 e+1}{e-1}$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\arccos\left(\ln \left(\frac{x+1}{x-3}\right)\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Horizontal asymptote $y=\frac{\pi}{2}$
$$\lim_{x\to \frac{-3-e}{e-1}}\arccos\left(\log \left(\frac{x+1}{x-3}\right)\right)=\pi$$
$$\lim_{x\to \frac{3 e+1}{e-1}}\arccos\left(\log \left(\frac{x+1}{x-3}\right)\right)=0$$
Derivative

$$y'=\frac{4}{(x-3) (x+1) \sqrt{1-\log ^2\left(\frac{x+1}{x-3}\right)}}$$
$y'>0$ for $x<-1\lor x>3$

---

[image]